# Help with video tutorial regarding Illustrator opacity mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, mask

OK, so I'm following this tutorial:

[**YouTube -- Illustrator Tutorial: Adding texture using a transparency mask**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPm5aUkq3OY)
<sub>--jump forward to 1:50</sub>

I do everything exactly as shown:

- first group object
- cut the texture
- select object
- go to transparency
- then *make opacity mask*.

After that, everything is gone as in video, but when I press CTRL+V to paste the texture (2:02 on video), it pastes just the texture itself, not the object WITH the texture.

This channel is not active anymore, so I can't ask the person who made it, I hope someone here had the same problem and can help.

Funny thing is that two days ago, I somehow managed to get the results, but now always the problem when pasting.

Comment: The tutorial works as expected. I just tried it. Looks like you've missed out selecting the Mask thumbnail before you pasted.

Comment: As I posted in comment below, it works for me, but only when using .jpeg texture. With vector, it still just pastes the texture, without making mask.

Comment: Ok, so try disabling the "clip" option, just before you paste into the mask.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat difficult to answer without seeing what you are doing. But perhaps a little explanation will help.

When the video pastes the texture, that's all it's pasting. It is *not* pasting the texture *and* the artwork. The only thing you *should* be pasting is the texture. It's the texture on the mask, in addition to the artwork on the artboard, that creates the combined appearance.

Make certain your texture is on the mask by clicking the **mask** thumbnail in the `Transparency` panel and that your artwork in on the artboard by clicking the **artboard** thumbnail on the `Transparency` panel. Then make certain both the texture and the artwork overlap.

You may also need to **tick/untick** the `Clip` and `Invert Mask` options on the Transparency panel. Either just one or both -- depends upon the texture you are using.

If you could show a screenshot of your artwork and the transparency panel, that may help to solve your issue further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got half results - I managed to make opacity mask without problems, BUT when using a .jpeg file. With the texture, always the same problem, it just pastes the texture. It shouldn't be different procedure for vector texture and raster image when making opacity mask if I'm not wrong. For the specific case, I used the .jpeg similar to texture, but for future I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments I think I know what the problem might be.

When you create the mask, and select the Mask thumbnail, deselect the "clip" option, before you paste it.

Here's an example of a vector object pasted as an opacity mask on some text.

[image]

Comment: Already tried it, as Scott also suggested it. It still pastes just the texture. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Hmm . . .  that's odd, because it clearly works, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to do it.